# Crashed in try! realm.write

Tags: realm

My Project Crashed in RealmUtil.swift line 16, the codes are shown below.
Is this mean that realm return nil?
I was quite confused. Hoping to get your help. 
Great Thanks!

**RealmUtil.swift**

```
15 let realm = try! Realm()
16 try! realm.write {
17      write()
18 }
```

detail log are as below.
It's shown in firebase, and I wasn't able to debug this in debug mode.

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1978b5ec4 __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1977d5724 pthread_kill$VARIANT$armv81 + 216
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x197725844 abort + 100
3  Realm                          0x1041bfe30 please_report_this_error_to_help_at_realm_dot_io + 10 
4  Realm                          0x1041c00fc realm::util::terminate_internal(std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&) + 264
5  Realm                          0x1041c0270 realm::util::terminate(char const*, char const*, long, std::initializer_list<realm::util::Printable>&&) + 324
6  Realm                          0x103eed0f4 realm::_impl::RealmCoordinator::advance_schema_cache(unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 182
7  Realm                          0x103fc0c2c realm::Realm::cache_new_schema() + 100
8  Realm                          0x103fc1510 realm::Realm::begin_transaction() + 176
9  Realm                          0x103f900e0 -[RLMRealm beginWriteTransaction] + 20
10 RealmSwift                     0x10477004c $s10RealmSwift0A0V5write16withoutNotifying_xSaySo20RLMNotificationTokenCG_xyKXEtKlF + 136
11 Ig Followers                   0x102da91c8 specialized static HomeViewModel.engagementAnalysis(media:) + 16 (RealmUtil.swift:16)
12 Ig Followers                   0x102da9408 specialized static HomeViewModel.analysisLTS() + 4301886472 (<compiler-generated>:4301886472)
13 Ig Followers                   0x102c84b2c closure #1 in closure #1 in HomeVC.getLTSData() + 4300688172 (<compiler-generated>:4300688172)
14 Ig Followers                   0x102dab644 partial apply for closure #1 in closure #1 in static HomeViewModel.getLTSData2(pk:completeHandler:) + 4301895236 (<compiler-generated>:4301895236)
15 Ig Followers                   0x102c9f454 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 4300797012 (<compiler-generated>:4300797012)
```

added image about detail function about this problem. 
[crashed_function_image_click_to_see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slCRM.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your code is correct and works for us so we won't be able to help with such a limited view of your code. Please provide more context; is this a full sync realm or local? How is realm initialized? What are you doing with threads? Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi ,Jay, I  added a image about the crashed function. Could you please help me to check this again,  many thanks.

Comment: I was not able to make this crash happen again (I tried many times). so it's hard for me to make the min project demo.

Comment: In general, please include code as text in your question so if we want to answer, we don't have to retype it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how the optionals are being handled. The issue is here

```
let lts = HVMlts()!
```

as that code force unwraps the return value guaranteeing HVMlts will *never* be nil.

However if you look at the associated functions, it can in fact, `return nil`.

```
if results.count == 1 {
   return results[0]
} else {
   return nil
}
```

If the Realm filter

```
let results = realm.objects(HomeViewModel.self)...
```

returns two or more results, then that function would return nil. Likewise if there were no results then it would also return nil

In either case that nil would cause your code to crash.

It's best to safely unwrap optionals or provide default values using a nil coalescing operator. I see you've done that in other parts of your code but here are two more options.

```
if let lts = HVMlts() then {
    //do something with lts as it's not nil
}
```

or

```
guard let lts = HVMlts() else { return }
//do something with lts
```